# My controller is not able to retrieve my session list from a Repository file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I have created a repository in this application and a session list is created in order to keep data in memory.  I am not able to retrieve my list from the controller in order to populate a grid view which I have.

This is my Repository

```
namespace ClientSearch.Repository
{
    public class Repo 
    {
        public HttpSessionStateBase session;

        public Repo (HttpSessionStateBase session)
        {
            this.session = session;
        }

        public void SetClient(ClientInfo client)
        {
            List<ClientInfo> mylist = new List<ClientInfo>();
            mylist = (List<ClientInfo>)this.session["test"];
        }

        public List<ClientInfo> GetClient()
        {
            return (List<ClientInfo>)session["list"];                
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Controller function

```
public ActionResult SearchClient()
{
    HttpSessionStateBase session = HttpContext.Session;
    Repo repo = new Repo(session);
    var result = repo.GetClient();
    return Json(new
    {
        list = result,
        count = result.Count
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

my setting control

```
public JsonResult ClientInformation(ClientInfo client)
{
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    result.Data = client;
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you get? What happens?

Comment: When I am returning Json from my controller I am getting a null value, I just noticed I am not setting it on my other controller.  I will update my my post

Comment: You realize that `test` is not the same string is `list` right?

Comment: dang I changed it so much I am missed that one, I wrote this on the fly because sharepoint was giving issue.  Now I am currently setting my set control

Comment: So, was that it? Does it work now?

Comment: This is a good reason not to use [magic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).  Instead use a variable and declare the variable like `private const string List = "list";` then `session[List]` will always be the same no matter what the value of list is.  Just be careful of collisions in Session.

Comment: Hey Ataravati I am setting an instance in my Client Information control but it is not pushing it to my repository.

Comment: That's a separate issue. But, the issue you had in this question was resolved, right? If yes, either update his question and explain what the new issue is or submit a new question.

Comment: Yes This question has been answered